# What is the purpose of using positive lookarounds over not?

Tags: regex

Say the string is ‘abc’ and the expression is (?=a)abc, would that not be the same as just searching for abc? When do positive lookarounds have purpose over not using them?

Comment: That positive lookahead is pointless as `a` is always an `a`. Do not use *pointless* lookarounds.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what'd be the expression to match `abc` only if preceded by `a` (as in `aabc`)? I find the syntax rather counter-intuitive...

Comment: You could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=a)abc` [(here is a small test)](https://regex101.com/r/y91J1b/1), here is some [Documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @juanlu Thank you! It was the ahead/behind terminology what was confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, **without making the u part of the match**. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Here is a small example from https://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/positive-examples-of-positive-and-negative-lookahead/

---

Say I want to retrieve from a text document all the words that are immediately followed by a comma. We’ll use this example string:

`What then, said I, shall I do?  You shan't, he replied, do anything.`

As a first attempt, I could use this regular expression to get one or more word parts followed by a comma:

```
[A-Za-z']+,
```

This yields four results over the string:

```
then,
I,
shan't,
replied,
```

Notice that this gets me the comma too, though, which I would then have to remove.  Wouldn’t it be better if we could express that we want to match a word that is followed by a comma without also matching the comma?

We can do that by modifying our regex as follows:

```
[A-Za-z']+(?=,)
```

This matches groups of word characters that are followed by a comma, but because of the use of lookahead the comma is not part of the matched text (just as we want it not to be).  The modified regex results in these matches:

```
then
I
shan't
replied
```